popup not function in openlayer
write code for maps portal of the city. I have problem with my code. I thing that problem is in my js file. I didn´t find answer here and in youtube, but code still not function. When I click on polygon in map, don´t show popup window with data from geoserver. and I'm just a student :) Can you help me please?
html code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Géoportail-Taza</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ressource/ol/ol.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ressource/layerswitcher/ol-layerswitcher.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="header">
        <img src="ressource/images/logo.jpg" alt="" style="width: inherit; height: inherit; vertical-align: middle;">
        <span style="vertical-align: middle;">Géoportail de Géotourisme</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="left">
        <div class="toc">
            <h3>Cartes</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" id="osm" name="osm" value="Open street Map" checked onchange="toggleLayer(event);">
            <label for="osm">OpenstreetMap</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="esri" name="esri" value="ESRI Satellite Imagery" checked onchange="toggleLayer(event);">
            <label for="esri">ESRI Satellite Imagery</label>
            <br>
            <h3>Couches</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" id="province" name="province" value="province_taza_pg" checked onchange="toggleLayer(event);">
            <label for="province">Taza</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="communes" name="communes" value="communes_taza_pg" checked onchange="toggleLayer(event);">
            <label for="communes">Communes de Taza</label>
            <br>
            <h4>Ressource Naturelles</h4>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Puits" name="Puits" value="PuitsTAZA" checked onchange="toggleLayer(event);">
            <label for="Puits">Source d'eaux</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Jbel" name="Jbel" value="Jbels_Haut_Inaouene" checked onchange="toggleLayer(event);">
            <label for="Jbel">Sommet de Montagne</label>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>
        <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
            <a href="#" id="popup-closer"> </a>
            <div id="popup-content"> </div>
            <div class="attQueryDiv" id="attQueryDiv">
                <div class="headerDiv" id="headerDiv">
                  <label for="">Attribute Query</label>
                </div>
                <br>
                <label for="selectLayer">Select Layer:</label>
                <select name="selectLayer" id="selectLayer">
                  <!-- Populate this select box with layer options -->
                </select><br><br>
                <label for="selectAttribute">Select Attribute:</label>
                <select name="selectAttribute" id="selectAttribute">
                  <!-- Populate this select box with attribute options -->
                </select><br><br>
                <label for="selectOperator">Select Operator:</label>
                <select name="selectOperator" id="selectOperator">
                  <!-- Populate this select box with operator options -->
                </select><br><br>
                <label for="enterValue">Enter Value:</label>
                <input type="text" name="enterValue" id="enterValue"><br><br>
                <button type="button" id="attQryRun" class="attQryRun" onclick="attributeQuery()">Run</button>
              </div>

        </div>

            </div>
        <div id="scale-line"></div>
        <div id="mouse-position"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<script src="ressource/ol/ol.js"></script>
<script src="ressource/layerswitcher/ol-layerswitcher.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`


and for javascript code
var mapView = new ol.View({
  center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-3.9980485, 34.2105603]),
  zoom: 8
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: mapView,
  controls: []
});

var osmTile = new ol.layer.Tile({
  title: 'Open Street Map',
  type: 'base',
  visible: true,
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

map.addLayer(osmTile);

var esriSatellite = new ol.layer.Tile({
  title: 'ESRI Satellite Imagery',
  visible: true,
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
      url: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
      attributions: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
  })
});

map.addLayer(esriSatellite);

var tazacommunesTile = new ol.layer.Tile({
  title: "communes_taza_pg",
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Prov_taza/wms',
    attributions:'geoserver',
      params: {'LAYERS':'Province_Taza:communes_taza_pg','TILED':true},
      serverType: 'geoserver',
      visible: true,
  })
});
tazacommunesTile.setOpacity(1);

map.addLayer(tazacommunesTile);

var tazaprovinceTile = new ol.layer.Tile({
  title: "province_taza_pg",
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Prov_taza/wms',
    params: {'LAYERS':'Province_Taza:province_taza_pg','TILED':true},
      serverType: 'geoserver',
      visible: true,
  })
});
tazaprovinceTile.setOpacity(0.2);

map.addLayer(tazaprovinceTile);



var jbelsHautInaoueneTile = new ol.layer.Tile({
  title: "Jbels_Haut_Inaouene",
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Prov_taza/wms',
    params: {'LAYERS':'Province_Taza:Jbels_Haut_Inaouene','TILED':true},
      serverType: 'geoserver',
      visible: true,
  })
});
jbelsHautInaoueneTile.setOpacity(0.4);

map.addLayer(jbelsHautInaoueneTile);

var puitsTile = new ol.layer.Tile({
  title: "PuitsTAZA",
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Prov_taza/wms',
    params: {'LAYERS':'Province_Taza:PuitsTAZA','TILED':true},
      serverType: 'geoserver',
      visible: true,
  })
});
puitsTile.setOpacity(0.4);

map.addLayer(puitsTile);

var layerswitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
  activationMode: 'click',
  startActive: false,
  groupSelectstyle: 'children'
});

map.addControl(layerswitcher);

var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
  coordinateFormat:ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  className: 'mouse-position'
});

map.addControl(mousePositionControl);

var scaleLineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine({
  units: 'metric',
  target: document.getElementById('scale-line'),
  className: 'ol-scale-line',
  bar: true,
  text: true
});

map.addControl(scaleLineControl);

function toggleLayer(e) {
  var lyrname = e.target.value;
  var checkedstatus = e.target.checked;
  var lyrList = map.getLayers();
  lyrList.forEach(function(element){
      if (lyrname === element.get('title')){
          element.setVisible(checkedstatus);
      }
  });
}
//GetFeature info
// Créer une couche de popup
const container = document.getElementById('popup');
const content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
const closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');

const overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element: container,
  autoPan: {
    animation: {
      duration: 250,
    },
  },
});
map.addOverlay(overlay);

closer.onclick = function () {
  overlay.setPosition(undefined);
  closer.blur();
  return false;
};

map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
  content.innerHTML = ''; // Effacer le contenu précédent
  var resolution = mapView.getResolution();
  var url = tazacommunesTile.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(evt.coordinate, resolution, 'EPSG:4326', {
    'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
    'propertyName': 'nom_commun,nom_comm_1'
  });

  if (url) {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      var feature = data.features[0];
      var props = feature.properties;
      content.innerHTML = "<h3> Commune : </h3> <p>" + props.nom_commun.toUpperCase() + "</p> <br> <h3> Communes 1: </h3> <p>" + props.nom_comm_1.toUpperCase() + "</p>";
      overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
    });
  } else {
    overlay.setPosition(undefined);
  }
});


// Create the home button
const homeButton = document.createElement('button');
homeButton.innerHTML = '<img src="/files/home.svg" alt="" style="width: 20px; height:20px; filter: brightness(0) invert(1); vertical-align: middle;">';
homeButton.className = 'myButton';

// Create the home button container
const homeElement = document.createElement('div');
homeElement.className = 'homeButtonDiv';
homeElement.appendChild(homeButton);

// Create the home control
const homeControl= new ol.control.Control({
  element: homeElement
});

// Add the home control to the map
map.addControl(homeControl);

// Add click event listener to the home button
homeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  location.href = "index.html";
});

// Create full screen control
const fsButton = document.createElement('button');
fsButton.innerHTML = '<img src="/files/fullscreen.svg" alt="" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; filter: brightness(0) invert(1);">';
fsButton.className = 'myButton';

const fsElement = document.createElement('div');
fsElement.className = 'fsButtonDiv';
fsElement.appendChild(fsButton);

const fsControl = new ol.control.Control({ element: fsElement });

fsButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const mapEle = document.getElementById("map");
  if (mapEle.requestFullscreen) {
    mapEle.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (mapEle.msRequestFullscreen) {
    mapEle.msRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (mapEle.mozRequestFullscreen) {
    mapEle.mozRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (mapEle.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    mapEle.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }
});

map.addControl(fsControl);
//test
// start: ZoomIn Control
var ZoomInInteraction = new ol.interaction.DragBox();

ZoomInInteraction.on('boxend', function () {
  var ZoomInExtent = ZoomInInteraction.getGeometry().getExtent();
  var zoomInFactor = 2; // Adjust this value to change the zoom level increase amount
  var newZoomLevel = map.getView().getZoom() + zoomInFactor;
  map.getView().fit(ZoomInExtent, {size: map.getSize(), duration: 250, maxZoom: newZoomLevel});
});

var ziButton = document.createElement('button');
ziButton.innerHTML = '<img src="files/zoomin.svg" alt="" salt="" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; filter: brightness(0) invert(1)">';
ziButton.className = 'myButton';
ziButton.id = 'ziButton';

var ziElement = document.createElement('div');
ziElement.className = 'ziButtonDiv';
ziElement.appendChild(ziButton);

var ZoomInFlag = false;
ziButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  ziButton.classList.toggle('clicked');
  ZoomInFlag = !ZoomInFlag;
  if (ZoomInFlag) {
    document.getElementById("map").style.cursor = 'zoom-in';
    map.addInteraction(ZoomInInteraction);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("map").style.cursor = 'auto';
    map.removeInteraction(ZoomInInteraction);
  }
});

var ziControl = new ol.control.Control({
  element: ziElement
});
map.addControl(ziControl);
// end: ZoomIn Control
// start: ZoomOut Control
var ZoomOutInteraction = new ol.interaction.DragBox();

ZoomOutInteraction.on('boxend', function () {
  var ZoomOutExtent = ZoomOutInteraction.getGeometry().getExtent();
  var zoomOutFactor = 2; // Adjust this value to change the zoom level decrease amount
  var newZoomLevel = map.getView().getZoom() - zoomOutFactor;
  map.getView().setZoom(newZoomLevel);
});

var zoButton = document.createElement('button');
zoButton.innerHTML = '<img src="/files/zoomOut.svg" alt="" salt="" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; filter: brightness(0) invert(1)">';
zoButton.className = 'myButton';
zoButton.id = 'zoButton';

var zoElement = document.createElement('div');
zoElement.className = 'zoButtonDiv';
zoElement.appendChild(zoButton);

var ZoomOutFlag = false;
zoButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  zoButton.classList.toggle('clicked');
  ZoomOutFlag = !ZoomOutFlag;
  if (ZoomOutFlag) {
    document.getElementById("map").style.cursor = 'zoom-out';
    map.addInteraction(ZoomOutInteraction);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("map").style.cursor = 'auto';
    map.removeInteraction(ZoomOutInteraction);
  }
});

var zoControl = new ol.control.Control({
  element: zoElement
});
map.addControl(zoControl);
// end: ZoomOut Control

// Create a button element for length measurement
var lengthButton = document.createElement('button');
lengthButton.innerHTML = '<img src="/files/Length.svg" alt="" salt="" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; filter: brightness(0) invert(1)">';
lengthButton.className = 'myButton';
lengthButton.id = 'lengthButton';

// Create a div element to hold the button
var lengthElement = document.createElement('div');
lengthElement.className = 'lengthButtonDiv';
lengthElement.appendChild(lengthButton);

// Create a new OpenLayers control for the length measurement button
var lengthControl = new ol.control.Control({
  element: lengthElement
})

// Initialize a flag to track the state of the length measurement tool
var lengthFlag = false;

// Add an event listener to the length button
lengthButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // Toggle the 'clicked' class on the button
  lengthButton.classList.toggle('clicked');
  
  // Toggle the lengthFlag
  lengthFlag =!lengthFlag;
  
  // Update the cursor style on the map
  document.getElementById("map").style.cursor = "default";
  
  if (lengthFlag) {
    // Remove any existing draw interaction
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    
    // Add a new draw interaction for LineString
    draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
      source: source,
      type: 'LineString',
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color:'#ffcc33',
          width: 2,
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 7,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#ffcc33',
          }),
        }),
      })
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw);
    createMesureTooltip();
    createHelpTooltip();

    var sketch;

    var pointerMoveHandler = function (evt) {
      if (evt.dragging) {
        return;
      }
      var helpMsg = 'Click to start drawing';
      if (sketch) {
        var geom = sketch.getGeometry();
        if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
          helpMsg = continueLineMsg;
        }
      }
      helpTooltipElement.innerHTML = helpMsg;
      helpTooltip.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
      helpTooltipElement.classList.remove('hidden');
    };

    map.on('pointermove', pointerMoveHandler);

    draw.on('drawstart', function (evt) {
        sketch = evt.feature;
        var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;
        sketch.getGeometry().on('change', function (evt) {
            var geom = evt.target;
            var output;
            if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
                output = formatLength(geom);
                tooltipCoord = geom.getLastCoordinate();
            }
            measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
            measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
        });
    });


    draw.on('drawend', function () {
        measureTooltipElement.ClassName='ol-tooltip ol-tooltip-static';
        measureTooltip.setOffset([0,-7]);
        sketch = null;
        measureTooltipElement = null;
        createMesureTooltip();
    });
  } else {
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    source.clear();
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("ol-tooltip ol-tooltip-static");
    while (elements.length > 0) elements[0].remove();
  }
});

// Add the length control to the map
map.addControl(lengthControl);

// Create a button element for area measurement
var areaButton = document.createElement('button');
areaButton.innerHTML = '<img src="/files/area.svg" alt="" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; filter: brightness(0) invert(1)">';
areaButton.className = 'myButton';
areaButton.id = 'removeButton';

var areaElement = document.createElement('div');
areaElement.className = 'areaButtonDiv';
areaElement.appendChild(areaButton);

var areaControl = new ol.control.Control({
  element: areaElement
})

var areaFlag = false;
areaButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  areaButton.classList.toggle('clicked');
  areaFlag = !areaFlag;
  document.getElementById("map").style.cursor = "default";

  if (areaFlag) {
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
      source: source,
      type: 'Polygon',
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color:'#ffcc33',
          width: 2,
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 7,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#ffcc33',
          }),
        }),
      })
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw);
    createMesureTooltip();
    createHelpTooltip();

    var sketch;

    var pointerMoveHandler =function (evt) {
      if (evt.dragging) {
        return;
      }
      var helpMsg = 'Click to start drawing';
      if (sketch) {
        var geom = sketch.getGeometry();
        if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
          helpMsg = continuePolygonMsg;
        }
      }
      helpTooltipElement.innerHTML = helpMsg;
      helpTooltip.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
      helpTooltipElement.classList.remove('hidden');
    };

    map.on('pointermove', pointerMoveHandler);

    draw.on('drawstart', function (evt) {
        sketch = evt.feature;
        var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;
        sketch.getGeometry().on('change', function (evt) {
            var geom = evt.target;
            var output;
            if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
                output = formatArea(geom);
                tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
            }
            measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
            measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
        });
    });


    draw.on('drawend', function () {
        measureTooltipElement.ClassName='ol-tooltip ol-tooltip-static';
        measureTooltip.setOffset([0,-7]);
        sketch = null;
        measureTooltipElement = null;
        createMesureTooltip();
    });
  } else {
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    source.clear();
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("ol-tooltip ol-tooltip-static");
    while (elements.length > 0) elements[0].remove();
  }
});

map.addControl(areaControl);

function createMesureTooltip() {
  if (measureTooltipElement) {
    measureTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(measureTooltipElement);
  }
  measureTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  measureTooltipElement.className = 'ol-tooltip ol-tooltip-measure';
  measureTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
    element: measureTooltipElement,
    offset: [0, -15],
    positioning: 'bottom-center'
  });
  map.addOverlay(measureTooltip);
}

function createHelpTooltip() {
  if (helpTooltipElement) {
    helpTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(helpTooltipElement);
  }
  helpTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
  helpTooltipElement.className = 'ol-tooltip hidden';
  helpTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
      element: helpTooltipElement,
      offset: [15, 0],
      positioning: 'center-left',
  });
  map.addOverlay(helpTooltip);
}

var continuePolygonMsg = 'Click to continue polygon, Double click to complete';
var continueLineMsg = 'Click to continue line, Double click to complete';

var draw;

var source = new ol.source.Vector();
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color:'#ffcc33',
      width: 2,
    }),
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 7,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#ffcc33',
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
map.addLayer(vector);
//test
var removeButton = document.createElement('button');
removeButton.innerHTML = '<img src="/files/remove.svg" alt="" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; filter: brightness(0) invert(1)">';
removeButton.className = 'myButton';
removeButton.id = 'removeButton';

var removeElement = document.createElement('div');
removeElement.className = 'removeButtonDiv';
removeElement.appendChild(removeButton);

var removeControl = new ol.control.Control({
  element: removeElement
});

map.addControl(removeControl);

removeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  map.removeLayer(vector);
  source.clear();
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("ol-tooltip ol-tooltip-static");
  while (elements.length > 0) elements[0].remove();
});
//add button
var geojson;
var featureOverlay;

var qryButton = document.createElement('button');
qryButton.innerHTML = '<img src="/files/query.svg" alt="" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; filter: brightness(0) invert(1)">';
qryButton.className = 'myButton';
qryButton.id = 'qryButton';

var qryElement = document.createElement('div');
qryElement.className = 'myButtonDiv';
qryElement.appendChild(qryButton);

var qryControl = new ol.control.Control({
  element: qryElement
});

var qryFlag = false;

qryButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // disableOtherInteraction('lengthButton');
  qryButton.classList.toggle('clicked');
  qryFlag = !qryFlag;
  document.getElementById("map").style.cursor = "default";
  if (qryFlag) {
    if (geojson) {
      geojson.getSource().clear();
      map.removeLayer(geojson);
    }
    if (featureOverlay) {
      featureOverlay.getSource().clear();
      map.removeLayer(featureOverlay);
      document.getElementById("map").style.cursor = "default";
      document.getElementById("attQueryDiv").style.display = "block";
      bolIdentify = false;
      addMapLayerList();
    }
  } else {
      document.getElementById("map").style.cursor = "default";
      document.getElementById("attQueryDiv").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("attListDiv").style.display = "none";
      if (geojson) {
          geojson.getSource().clear();
          map.removeLayer(geojson);
          if (featureOverlay) {
              featureOverlay.getSource().clear();
              map.removeLayer(featureOverlay);
          }
      }
  }
})
map.addControl(qryControl);

I will be so thankfull if anyone can help for real <3
I try to show the attribute of the layer that I added from geoserver and It does'nt function and the samething for length and area mesuring and qrybutton

do you get anything from getFeatureInfoUrl?
